# Haskell の レコード構文(Record Syntax)にて、簡潔なフィールド名を定義すると重複しやすい問題の解決方法

Tags: haskell

Haskell の レコード構文(Record Syntax)にて、簡潔なフィールド名を使い定義すると名前がかぶりやすくなる問題があります。

[参考サイト](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/defining-types-streamlining-functions.html#deftypes.record) を見ると、レコード名をprefixとしたフィールド名を使うとよいようですが、こんなものなのでしょうか？
よりよい方法はないものでしょうか？

エラーになる例:

```haskell
data Java = Java { power :: Integer ; url :: String }
data Link = Link { title :: String ; url :: String }
-- 下記が定義されるためか、重複してしまう
-- url :: Java -> String
-- url :: Link -> String
```

エラー内容:

> Multiple declarations of ‘url’
>   Declared at: (省略)

---

改善した例:

```haskell
data Java = Java { javaPower :: Integer ; javaUrl :: String }
data Link = Link { linkTitle :: String ; linkUrl :: String }
```

---

※ 「命名規則や用語がHaskell的に変」という場合もぜひ、コメントや編集などでフィードバックお願いします

Answer (score 10, accepted):

7.10現在、GHCでは重複したフィールド名をうまく扱うことができません。しかし、GHC 7.12からは、OverloadedRecordFields(https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Records/OverloadedRecordFields/Design)と呼ばれる拡張が導入される予定で、それを使えば同名のフィールドを定義できます。

OverloadedRecordFieldsを利用すると、urlに以下のような型を持たせることができます。

```
url :: r { url :: String } => r -> Integer
```

`r { url :: String }`は、レコード`r`が`url :: String`というフィールドを持っているという制約を示しており、フィールド名によるオーバーロードが可能になります。

また、現在のHaskell(GHC)でオーバーロードされたフィールドを実現する研究は多数存在し(https://wiki.haskell.org/Extensible_record)、盛んにライブラリも作られています。

最近リリースされたrecordというライブラリは、Template Haskellを用いて、OverloadedRecordFieldsを使わずにそれに近い記述を可能にしています。作者のページ(http://nikita-volkov.github.io/record/)で解説されていますが、インターフェイスは比較的シンプルで、パフォーマンス上のデメリットも少ないため、お勧めできます。recordを使うと、JavaとLinkの例はこのようになります。

```
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuoters #-}
import Record
import Record.Lens

type Java = [r| { power :: Integer, url :: String } |]
type Link = [r| { title :: String, url :: String } |]

example :: Link
example = [r|{ title = "example", url = "http://www.example.org" }|]

-- view [l|url] :: Java -> String
-- view [l|url] :: Link -> String
```

宣伝になってしまいますが、私もこの問題に取り組んでいて、[extensible](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/extensible)というライブラリを開発しています。こちらは、まずフィールド名と型をあらかじめ決めるというアプローチをとっているので、ほかの言語における構造体とは毛色が異なります。

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell, DataKinds, TypeOperators, TypeFamilies, FlexibleContexts #-}
import Data.Extensible.Record
import Data.Extensible.Record.Internal.Rig

mkField "power" [t|Integer|]
mkField "url" [t|String|]
mkField "title" [t|String|]

type Java = Record '["power", "url"]
type Link = Record '["title", "url"]

example :: Link
example = title @= "example" 
       <: url @= "www.example.org"
       <: Nil
-- view url :: "url" ∈ xs => Record xs -> String
```

OverloadedRecordFieldsはフィールドが第一級でない、recordはTemplate Haskellが必要、extensibleを含む拡張可能レコードはパフォーマンスがあまり良くないというデメリットがあり、Haskellerの間でも共通の答えは出ていないのが現状です。

Comment: 僕自身入門レベルなのですが，もうちょっと手軽には，「とりあえずモジュールに分けて qualified import する」というのがあると認識しています（例えば J.url と L.url にできる）．これは「アリ」なんでしょうか？

Comment: モジュールに分けるというのももっとも簡単な選択の一つだと思います。
OverloadedRecordFieldsが提案されたきっかけは、接頭辞をつけるかモジュール単位に分けるのが実用的でない場合が多いことなので(https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Records/OverloadedRecordFields/Design)、背景にある正直な対処法としては接頭辞かモジュールに分けることが挙げられます。

Answer (score 9):

私が知っている、もっとも簡単な対処法はLensを利用することです。

`lens`ライブラリを使う場合、もっとも簡単に書けば以下のようになります。

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
import Control.Lens

data Java  =  Java  { javaPower ::  Integer  ; javaUrl ::  String  } 
data Link  =  Link  { linkTitle ::  String   ; linkUrl ::  String  } 

makeFields ''Java
makeFields ''Link
```

すると、両方に対して使える`url`コンビネータが"lens"として定義され、`power`と`title`もlensとしてそれぞれの型に対し定義されます。

"^."、".~"、"&"演算子で、これらのLensを使ってレコードを操作することができます。

```
ghci> Java 12 "http://..." ^. url
"http://..."

ghci> Java 12 "http://..." & power .~ 9000
Java 9000 "http://..."

ghci> Link "start" "http://..." ^. url
"http://..."

ghci> Link "start" "http://..." & title .~ "end"
Link "end" "http://..."
```

`lens`のチュートリアルや発表は、私のも含めインターネット上に多数存在します。

そのほとんどは英語ですが、少なくとも1つは、[`its_out_of_tune`](https://twitter.com/its_out_of_tune)さんが以前の*勉強会*で発表した日本語のものがあります。

ちゅーんさんのスライドは今でも閲覧できます。

http://www.slideshare.net/itsoutoftunethismymusic/ekmett-17955009

残念ながら、発表は録画されていたのですが、もうUstreamには残っていないようです。(▰˘︹˘▰)